# Has No exported member Auth in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, export, components

I'm New to React Programming.
When I tried to Import "Auth" class exported as

```
export default class Auth
```

in My Home component

```
import { AUTH_CONFIG } from './auth0-variables';
```

I'm getting error "**Module has No exported member as Auth**"

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between default and named exports.

For default exports, omit the brackets when importing. `import AuthConfig from './auth0-variables'` should work.

You'll use the brackets for importing **named** exports. For example, if you had `export const myConst = 42` in a module somewhere, you'd import it as `import { myConst } from './file.js`.

For more about named and default exports read up on the [`export` docs from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export). There are multiple examples on using default and named exports to make grasping it easier.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :)